# What is the modulus operator (%) in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, modulus

I have this line:

```
randomIndex = Int(drand48() % Double(alphabetColors.count))
```

And Xcode 8 (Swift 3) tells me:

```
'%' is unavailable: Use truncatingRemainder instead
```

Is there no operator anymore? How should I convert my code?

Comment: The % operator is a remainder operation not a modulo operator in Swift. Here is some talk about it: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160523/018679.html

Comment: I have done this way..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769128/5315917

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can simply follow the diagnostic message:

```
let randomIndex = Int(drand48().truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: Double(alphabetColors.count)))
```

Or using `arc4random_uniform(_:)` would be a better alternative.

```
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(alphabetColors.count)))
```

Answer (score 34):

[image]

This seems to be available for me, currently on Swift 3.1, so possible it was added back.

My guess is that it's somewhere in Foundation and needs an explicit `import Foundation`

**Update**

This is for Int types only. It seems that for doubles, truncating remainder is required.

Comment: That's odd, I can't find anything about it on https://apple.github.io/swift-evolution/ for Swift 3.1. Isn't there a third party library on your side which can induce this behaviour?

Comment: Oh you are right, I found a paragraph about it on the official documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html
They call it the **remainder** operator

Answer (score 15):

Cast your variable to `Int` before mod

example

```
let result = Int(value) % 3
```

Answer (score 5):

As per new Guideline Swift 5, it's changed

```
value.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to find the modulus of 2 numbers.
label.text is to display the result in a label that I have already designed

```
let result = Int(num1) % Int(num2)
label.text = String(Int(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884269-remainder

If you use truncatingRemainder (as mentioned in the other comments) then it is going to floor the value first, which means 3.14 is going to become 3.