# How to do modular arithmetics on big numbers in Swift?

Tags: swift, biginteger, modular-arithmetic

This comes up when evaluating a rolling hash of a string by subtracting the old weight of a character and adding a new weight for a new character.

Python has infinite length digits and is able to store such large numbers:

```
num = -56061846576641933068511861128435847024473459936647893758520084401988341
div = 10**9 + 7
mod = num % div #504892002
```

But in Swift, as I keep doing calculations, I lose precision and get bigger and bigger errors. For example, at some point in my calculations, the above number had this value:

```
var num = Double("-5.606184657664193e+70")
var div = pow(Double(10), 9) + 7
var mod = num!.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: div)
mod = mod < 0 ? mod + div : mod //215272131.0
```

I looked into Decimal, but it [does not support the mod operation](https://forums.swift.org/t/remainder-mod-for-decimal/40737). And Int64 will also be too small for such numbers. Are there any other native options, without adding convenience extensions?

Also, [How do you get the int and modulo (mod) of division with an NSDecimalNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175595/how-do-you-get-the-int-and-modulo-mod-of-division-with-an-nsdecimalnumber?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not help. It suggests extensions or has examples that do not deal with big numbers.

Comment: How could -5.606184657664193e+70 possibly be exactly equal to -56061846576641933068511861128435847024473459936647893758520084401988341?

Comment: Okay, I see the issue. I guess my question is, in swift how would I operate on such numbers? Is UInt64 the right data type? The problem is that I am losing precision as my calculation keeps getting bigger. Python has infinite length of numbers so I do not run into this issue.

Comment: Looks like [Decimal does not support mod](https://forums.swift.org/t/remainder-mod-for-decimal/40737) :/. Is there any built-in way to do this? Kinda frustrating that something so simple in Python is almost impossible to do in Swift natively.

Comment: Could you also help me out by casting a re-open vote? I have update the question and I think it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: I agree that your question is much better now. Can you show an example of how you got the number you have? I suspect that you can do the modulo operations as you go and never exceed 1e9+7

Comment: Thanks! Hang on let me add how I got there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the int and modulo (mod) of division with an NSDecimalNumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175595/how-do-you-get-the-int-and-modulo-mod-of-division-with-an-nsdecimalnumber)

Comment: @MadPhysicist `hash -= weight`,  `weight = id(old) * pow(Double(base), Double(len - 1))`, when len is 50 and base is 26, old id 1, the weight becomes `2.156224868332382e+69`

Comment: @Parth. I feel like basic number theory says that you don't need to go that far. Even without looking it up, I can write a loop that takes N to the power 49 modulo whatever without any overflow. Does Swift have an int64 type?

Comment: It has an int64 type. But IIRC I had an overflow with that too. Let me get an example if I can.

Comment: Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation. The idea is to implement `pow(base, len - 1) mod div` in a way that does not overflow to begin with. Integer math is better than float when you can use it.

Comment: So the problem is 26\**49 is `2.156224868332382e+69`. And Int64 max is `9223372036854775807`. So I can't cast it. And 26\**49 % 1e9+7 will again lose the precision that python has, right?

Comment: @Parth Why do you think the question I suggested doesn't apply? It shows how to do modulus using `NSDecimalNumber`. You can create big numbers with `NSDecimalNumber`. It's just what you need.

Comment: I was looking for something built in. I think the question you showed used extensions. Can we do it without adding more code or relying on ObjC type? Wanted something clean and simple. Example, this is too verbose: `let quotient = dividend.dividing(by: divisor, withBehavior: NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .down, scale: 0, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: false))`

Comment: @Parth The question I linked has an answer in Swift.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769128/7946143) answer?  It is quite involved.

Comment: @Parth Yes. It's 5 lines of code versus your 4 lines. How is that "quite involved"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigInteger equivalent in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531914/biginteger-equivalent-in-swift)

Comment: @HangarRash, FYI, currently Swift has no built-in big integer(arbitrary precision) API. The NSDecimalNumber only supports mantissa up to 38 digits long.

Comment: @relent95 was looking for something built-in and clean to use. I guess it is not supported ATM.

Comment: @MadPhysicist gave you a wikipedia link that has algorithms that let you compute your value using only the int64 type.

Comment: You can either write the code yourself or use code someone else wrote. The built in features have finite scope, so a conclusive "no" in that regard is possible. You don't want to use code other people wrote. So the only remaining option is to buckle down and implement one of the algorithms I linked to, or something else, like your own home-baked big int implementation.

Comment: Mad Physicist, @PresidentJames, FYI, the OP wants the modular operation, not the modular exponentiation. A popular algorithm for the former is the [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), and one for the latter is Montgomery modular exponentiation. See the Algorithm D in Knuth or HAC 14.20 for example.

Comment: @relent95: You missed his comment where he explains where that large integer comes from.

Comment: President James, I missed that. Thanks. The OP needs to edit the question. It is an XY problem. He doesn't need a big integer API for that purpose only.

Comment: Long story short, there is no native way in Swift to do this right now. And if I wanted to deal with modular arithmetic of very large numbers, I would have to implement a custom algo. What still confuses me about that is Swift can't accurately hold big exponents like -26^49. Then how will I get accuracy in doing `-26^49 % 10^9+7`?

Comment: See [Memory-efficient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Memory-efficient_method). Let m = 10000000007. Think about these: r_1 = (m-26) % m, r_2 = (r_1 * 26) % m, r_3 = (r_2 * 26) % m, ... r_49 = (r_48 * 26) % m. The r_i *26 will not overflow because r_i < m, r_i * 26 < m * 26 < 2^63-1.

Comment: Long story short, no one will give you a copy & paste answer, but you have been shown a wikipedia link that explains in great detail how to do exactly what you claim to want.